# Pass IEnumerable ViewModel to View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, mvvm

I have two Tables, `Product` & `ProductImages`

````````````````````````
+---PRODUCT----+
| ID           |
| Name         |
```````````````

+---PRODUCT Images----+
| ID                  |
| ProductId           |
| URL                 |
```````````````````````
````````````````````````

I want to display the data in my `Index View` from both the tables via `ViewModel`

Here are my ViewModel

```
public class ProductDisplayViewModel{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string Name {get; set;}        
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }

}

public class ProductIenumViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<ProductDisplayViewModel> productDisplayViewModel { get; set; }
}
```

That's my Controller

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {

        var product = new ProductDisplayViewModel
        {
            //ProductId = db.Products.Select(s => s.Id).ToString,
            Name = db.Products.Select(s => s.Name).ToString(),
            ImageUrl = db.ProductImages.Select(s => s.URL).ToString()
        };


        var productIenumViewModel = new ProductIenumViewModel
        {
            productDisplayViewModel =  new List<ProductDisplayViewModel> { product }
        };

        return View(productIenumViewModel);
    }
```

But I get the error that I have passed `ViewModel.ProductIenumViewModel` but this dictionary requires a model item of type `'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable 1[ViewModel.ProductDisplayViewModel]'`

if I use `productDisplayViewModel =  IEnumerable<ProductDisplayViewModel>  product` in my Controller I get the error that `ProductDisplayViewModel` is a type but is used like variable

**Edit**
**This is my View**

```
@model IEnumerable<MyApp.Areas.Admin.ViewModel.ProductDisplayViewModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped" >
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </th>      
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ImageUrl)
        </th>  
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ImageUrl)
        </td>

        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.ProductId }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.ProductId }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.ProductId })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Comment: What's your view declaration?

Comment: It sounds like your view's model is `IEnumerable<ProductIEnumViewModel>`, where it should just be `ProductIEnumViewModel`. Or, even better, get rid of `ProductIEnumViewModel` and use `IEnumerable<ProductDisplayViewModel>` as your model.

Comment: I second that, would be nice to see the the view. Also, it seems like you stripped quite a part of the controller action but now the code does not make much sense as it is unlikely to even build...

Comment: this code looks like it has way more issues than that.. how does `Name = db.Products.Select(s => s.Name).ToString()` or `ImageUrl = db.ProductImages.Select(s => s.URL).ToString()` work for you?

Comment: @JamieD77 I don't know, but it didn't give me any compile error because I am not able to display the view, or if you could write a pseudo code, what Should I do to make it proper code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Besides the error you're getting, you're not forming your `IEnumerable<ProductDisplayViewModel>` correctly.

Your controller code should look something like this assuming that your view has a `@model IEnumerable<ProductDisplayViewModel>`

```
public ActionResult Index()
{

    var products = db.ProductImages
                     .Include("Product")
                     .Select(a => new ProductDisplayViewModel {
                          ProductId = a.ProductID,
                          Name = a.Product.Name,
                          ImageUrl = a.URL
                     });
    return View(products );
}
```

Comment: Well, thanks for the simple answer, Now I understand better, can you explain a little, why did you included `Products` on `ProductImages` why no the Include `ProductImages` on `Product`

Comment: The `.Include("Products")` tells EF to lazy load the `Products` collection for `ProductImages`.. this gives you access to the `Product` properties like `Id` and `Name`.   Since your query is querying from `db.ProductImages` to begin with you already have access to it's properties so there's no reason to include `ProductImages`   You dont need the `.Include` in where statements so you might not need it in the `.Select` statement to get the Product properties.. i just added it to be safe